# sh equivalent of this bash command that reads from a named pipe

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, sh

I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent version of the following bash command(s) is in sh, first, say I have a named pipe called myfifo and I run:

```
cat <(echo hello) myfifo
```

I get

```
hello
```

then it waits for something to be written to myfifo, if on another terminal I run:

```
echo world > myfifo
```

finally I get:

```
hello
world
```

then the command terminates and I'm back at the shell ready to write new commands. This is what you'd expect from that command, I want to replicate this exact behavior in sh. Now since sh doesn't have process substitution an alternative command would be:

```
echo hello | cat - myfifo
```

if I run that in bash I again get the same behaviour as the first command BUT if I run that in sh the command NEVER ENDS, what I mean by that is that I do get hello and then it waits to print whatever is written to myfifo which it does do but once it does it doesn't terminate, the only things I can do then is Ctrl-C out of it or keep piping stuff into myfifo which it keeps printing. This seems to be something specific to sh since in bash you get the same behaviour as

```
cat <(echo hello) myfifo
```

Does anyone know what can I do so it does the same in sh??? by the way I'm running this on mac, haven't tried it on linux yet but I need it to run on mac.

Comment: Your second version works fine for me in `sh`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have another process writing to `myfifo`? That will prevent `cat` from reading EOF from the named pipe.

Comment: no, did you run it on mac or linux?

Comment: I ran it on MacOS Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

Availability of named pipes is dependent on the OS, not the shell.

You can use them like this, whether on `bash` or `sh`:

```
mkfifo myfifo
echo foo > myfifo
cat myfifo
```

Or with file descriptors:

```
mkfifo myfifo

exec 3<> myfifo
echo foo >&3
cat <&3

# close fd
exec 3>&-
```

The `<(cmd)` or `>(cmd)` syntax is process substitution, which is slightly different. It’s used to substitute a file argument with a command’s input or output. It’s implemented in `bash` and other shells, but not POSIX `sh`.

process substitution example:

```
grep pattern <(echo foo)
```

Or

```
curl -o >(grep pattern) https://example.com/foo.txt
```

From `man bash`

> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.

Comment: Just to mention, `mkfifo` is required by the POSIX specification, while `/dev/fd` is not. I *think* `/dev/fd` is used by `bash` if both are available, though (more efficient, if you don't have to create an explicit file system entry first?).